# Freeing abstract class pointers

Tags: c++, virtual, new-operator, abstract, delete-operator

In C++ I have a `class A` that has an abstract class pointer to allow for polymorphism contained in a `class B`, I have another pointer to an abstract `class C` that allocates a concrete instance of a child class of `class B` into that memory and I need to call a cleanup (see question below) function from `class C` to deallocate the memory taken by the child class of `class B` that I allocated from the heap, the problem is I can't guarantee I have access to the cleanup function because I only have a pointer to `class C` which I can't just copy, because it could be gone by the time I call need to destroy the containing `class A`.

In order to solve the problem of not having access to the cleanup function can I call delete on the `class A` pointer even though I'm pointing to a child class? **Does C++ new also store heap block size like malloc so that you can just delete memory referenced by a pointer to an abstract class like this?** If not is there another way to organize the program that allows me to handle the situation?

Comment: The actual code would be a bit convoluted, as you might tell from just the summary of it, if someone answers the main question negatively and I need to restructure all my class I can post the code and maybe clarify the situation a bit more.

Comment: Unfortunately the summary is much harder to follow than actual code. Don't post your real-life code, though, but make a **minimal, complete** example that exhibits your problem. Usually such code would begin with `class Foo {`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using my crystal ball because it's hard to follow your question but you probably need virtual destructors.

Comment: Just look at the bolded part really, the backstory is a bit messy. My main question is about deleting memory referenced by a virtual class pointer, is it safe to do that, assuming my destructors are virtual?

Comment: Good crystal ball skills! Now tell me why my 3D anaglyph DirectX web app doesn't get enough FPS...

Comment: sagittarius: the constellation of mars and jupiter and the strong lunatic activity influences your zodiac. This is not a good time period to develop your DirectX app.

Answer (score 4):

The standard states (§5.3.5 ¶3):

> In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

If I understood correctly, you have an object of some derived type, and you hold a pointer to it whose static type is one of its base classes; so, you're ok, as far as you have `virtual` destructors.

---

***Edit*** well, I was way too slow :P